# DAX: Count unique observations in related table

Tags: excel, dax, powerpivot

I have two datasets: a firm-database with all the firms listed and relations-database that tracks ownership of the firms. 
In the relations-dataset, if a firm has 8 owners, the firm has 8 rows in the dataset, one for each owner. Owners can own multiple firms and can own the same firm through different companies, meaning that an owner can appear multiple times in one firm.
I need a calculated column in the firm database that counts how many unique owners there are per firm.

I tried this:

```
=CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT(relations[owner]); 
         FILTER(relations; relations(firm)=Firm(firm)
```

but Excel PowerPivot keeps crashing when I try to enter the command.

Comment: You can't count a table, you need to reference a column within a table i.e. 
DISTINCTCOUNT('relations'[some column name])), try using countrows instead ;)

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I did make it on a column in the related table. I edited it in the question. The question still stands.

Comment: can you post a pic of your model and your desired output